# Is there an analogous definition of orthogonality for functions of more than one variable?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, orthogonality

The title says it all;

> Is there a concept of orthogonality of functions where the functions are of several variables?

For example, according to the wikipedia page on orthogonal functions, functions $f$ and $g$ are orthogonal if

$$\left<f, g \right> = \int_If(x)g(x)\ dx = 0$$

where $I$ is an interval. What if we have $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ and some domain $D$? Can we say that $f$ and $g$ are orthogonal on $D$ if

$$\iint_D f(x,y)g(x,y)\ dxdy = 0$$

Comment: The hydrogenic wavefunctions are a good example of multivariate orthogonal functions, so yes, this concept exists.

Comment: All you need to define orthogonality is an inner product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space